# firewall issue with RTSP server on iOS

Tags: rtsp, rtsp-client

I'm trying to set up an rtsp server on my iphone to stream video content(C / objective-C). It works great on local but I can't connect to my iphone from network :

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://82.101.X.X -f flv test.flv
>TCP connection to 82.101.X.X:554 failed: Connection refused
>rtsp://82.101.X.X: Input/output error
```

I'm almost certain this fails because of firewalls&routers but i don't know how to solve this because I believe client have to initiate a connection (PLAY request ?). I'm new to theses protocols, any sample/help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup a port forwarding rule on your router to routing incoming connections on port 554 to your iPhone's internal IP (typically a 192.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x address)

http://portforward.com/ has tutorials for how to do this on most routers.

Additionally, you'll probably want to get your iPhone a static IP so that when you leave your house and return, you won't have to setup Port Forwarding every time (again, this is done from your router Config)

Finally if you don't have a static IP from your ISP (meaning, if your external IP is not always 82.101.x.x) you should setup a dynamic DNS with a free service like dyndns.org